# Bootstrap - box border collapses span width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using the box borders from http://css3pie.com/ in bootstrap. When the containers and the spans are fluid the boxes take the right width of span4, span8.
When the row width is fixed, the boxes shrink in width. What is the problem?

The markup:

```
  <div class="container"> 

      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span8 box">
```

The CSS (box):

```
border: 1px solid #696;
padding: 60px 0;
text-align: center; width: 200px;
-webkit-border-radius: 8px;
-moz-border-radius: 8px;
border-radius: 8px;
-webkit-box-shadow: #666 0px 2px 3px;
-moz-box-shadow: #666 0px 2px 3px;
box-shadow: #666 0px 2px 3px;
background: #EEFF99;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#EEFF99), to(#66EE33));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#EEFF99, #66EE33);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#EEFF99, #66EE33);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#EEFF99, #66EE33);
background: -o-linear-gradient(#EEFF99, #66EE33);
background: linear-gradient(#EEFF99, #66EE33);
-pie-background: linear-gradient(#EEFF99, #66EE33);
behavior: url(/pie/PIE.htc);
```

I am looking at fixed row design, like -

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span8 box">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps:
  http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/3gHGQ/

I've added 2 things to your CSS:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

You are using a border in your styling which adds width to the div and will clash with the Bootstrap grid.

Secondlly I'm forcing the box to be full width with

```
width:620px !important;
```

You need a better mind than mine explain why the box collapses when it's not a fluid row, but the above CSS solves the problem.

Good luck!

Comment: I refined http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/3gHGQ/ .  I replaced the css with a responsive file and added some @media requests to change the width of the box div at various breakpoints. Here's the result: http://fiddle.jshell.net/panchroma/3gHGQ/show/